# C# + SQL + Xamarin Android:

Tags: c#, sql, xamarin.android, sqldataadapter

I've been stumped on this problem for a while, and although I have searched up my problems online, I haven't had much luck. So in my Android program made in Xamarin, in the button click event, I try to send data to the server, however, I would get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Update requires the command clone to have a connection object. The Connection property of the command clone has not been initialized.

I am using this code at this point:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter($"Select * from Room", connection);
    SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

    Spinner roomsSPNR = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.rooms);
    int room = Convert.ToInt32(roomsSPNR.SelectedItem.ToString());
    DataRow[] selected = rooms.Tables[0].Select($"RoomNo = {room}");
    selected[0][3] = Id;

    dataAdapter.Update(rooms);  //Line giving the error
}
changeColors(Id);
```

I'm stumped on this, I can't really figure out why it is doing this. Can anyone help? 
I have tried:

1. Setting the update.connection manually
2. Making an SQL command and putting the command builder's command into there(There is another error)
3. Setting the DataAdapter's update command to the method for the command builder
4. In the DataAdapter's initialization, I have changed the connection to the connection string
5. Many others that may not have any importance

Edit: Earlier in the code the program is able to read from the server and put it into 'rooms. On the other hand, I'm not familiar with making web services; is that what I need to do to allow it to update the database?

Comment: The code is running on your device, the SQL server isn't. You should use something like a REST web api to make requests to the server, which in turn should deal with the SQL.

Comment: Alternatively, if you only need a local database, use SQLite.

Comment: @FraukeNonnenmacher It is an actual server, is the only way to get this to work by using a web service?

Comment: Yes, I would recommend a standard WEB API. There's a tutorial about that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/consuming/rest

Comment: I tried doing exactly this a while back. I did not want to make a web service and I just wanted to access the database directly from my app. It is not possible. Take a look at this thread on xamarin fourms https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44392/connect-mobile-application-to-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly connect with a database in xamarin. You need to first create a webservice and use that web service to insert or fetch data from database.

If you need I will help you with webservices.